# #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) nested query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1241

i found this error when I enter  this command

```
SELECT *
FROM  Borrowed_Book , User
WHERE User.UserId=Borrowed_Book.UserId  IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Book , Book_version_info
    WHERE 
        Book_version_info.PublisherID = 1 AND 
        Book.ISBN= Book_version_info.Book_ISBN
);
```

i cannot find what's the issue here and why i get this error
I search on the internet but I don’t find the reason

Comment: What do you believe `WHERE a = b IN ( ... )` means, and why do you believe that? Perhaps if you took another look at how the `IN` clause works, it might be illuminating, e.g. web search for [`sql in subquery`](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+in+subquery).

Comment: What you try to achieve by your query?

Comment: Please do your homework on your own or use the search function to find a suitable answer here ;-)

Comment: "i found this error when I enter this command", What error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should match your columns in the IN function:

```
WHERE User.UserId=Borrowed_Book.UserId  IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM Book , Book_version_info
    WHERE 
        Book_version_info.PublisherID = 1 AND 
        Book.ISBN= Book_version_info.Book_ISBN
);
```

SQL does not know what to do with that the columns should be same so try instead:

```
WHERE User.UserId=Borrowed_Book.UserId  AND User.UserId IN (
    SELECT User.UserId
    FROM Book , Book_version_info, User
    WHERE 
        Book_version_info.PublisherID = 1 AND 
        Book.ISBN= Book_version_info.Book_ISBN
);
```